# Python error - “ImportError: No module named”

Tags: python, python-import

First of all this is what my directory looks like:

```
.:
ref.py   main.py   utility

./utility:
file_manip.py
```

When I execute `main.py` I get this error:

```
>>> python main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import utility.file_manip as fm
ImportError: No module named utility.file_manip
```

I cannot for the life of me get to the bottom of this. Clearly utility.file_manip exists...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a blank `__init__.py` file in your utility directory in order for Python to see it as a package. See [the tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages).

Comment: Thank you! This worked, but why? I've executed the same files on a different computer and it worked without an `__init__.py` file